# How to sync Google Calendar gcalcli with Conky/Desktop?

Tags: package-management, python, conky

I want to sync my Google Calendar with the Linux Mint 17.2 desktop; preferably through Conky. I'm aware of a method using Thunderbird but I'd rather have it set up as [described here](http://xmodulo.com/integrate-google-calendar-linux-desktop.html). Following the steps, however, I encounter a number of errors (such as `ImportError: No module named _MozillaCookieJar` among others) and I couldn't manage doing the steps right. Comments in the link update some of the outdated steps but it seems some info is still missing. I tried looking for more updated links and [came across this](https://allensmith.net/wiki/kb:linux:conky_gcalcli), but again seems the steps don't work properly. Can anyone point out exactly what to do (baby steps please)?

**Details:** When I do the first step from [the first link](http://xmodulo.com/integrate-google-calendar-linux-desktop.html), I try `sudo pip install google-api-python-client` and I get the `ImportError: No module named _MozillaCookieJar` error. 
When I tried [the second link](https://allensmith.net/wiki/kb:linux:conky_gcalcli), I got to the step where it says `pip install vobject parsedatetime` and even after updating `parsedatetime` I still get the same `ImportError: No module named _MozillaCookieJar` error after trying `pip install vobject parsedatetime` a second time after updating. Maybe it's something wrong with `pip`?

Either way, I broke this question down into "Main Question" and "Details" because I think even if the "details" are fixed, I'll run into another bad step eventually and so if there is an easier way of going about this, please let me know.

Comment: What versions of python/pip are you running?

Comment: @JesseKeilson it says I'm using Python 2.7.6, not sure how to check what version pip is (when I tried sudo apt-get install pip it said it was unable to locate the package)

Comment: I'm asking because of this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9857677/python-3-2-wont-import-cookielib

Looks like there were some name changes in some of the dependencies. You'll probably want to try installing python3 `sudo yum install python3` and then for pip, try `apt-cache search pip` to figure out the right package name, though I'm pretty sure it's python-pip.

Comment: @JesseKeilson I think gcalcli says it won't work with python3; I used `apt-cache search pip` and you're right, it's `python-pip`  but that's already installed apparently so I don't think that's the problem either.

Comment: Right you are! Let me read a little closer before I make more comments that don't apply.